# Mouse pointer disappears when using drawing tablet on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, mouse, drawing

I have an Aiptek drawing tablet which worked perfectly on Win7 but has a problem on Win8. The problem is that the mouse pointer disappears when I am using the tablet. On Win7, I could hover the stylus over the tablet and control the mouse by moving it around without touching the tablet but on Win8 it completely disappears leaving me to guess where I have to put the stylus down. This is very frustrating as I usually click on something I don't want or draw in the wrong place.
Is there any settings I can change?

Answer (score 0):

Install the driver for your tablet from Aiptek's download page. Old hardware like this is not plug-and-play.